# Grails - MongoDB and plugin domain classes

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-domain-class, database

I need Hibernate as some of the plugins I am using depend on it. 
So I use both MongoDB and Hibernate plugins.

Is there a way to make plugin domain classes handled by MongoDB without editing directly the domain class file ? What would be the cleanest way to do that ?

Any suggestion is most welcome. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

of course there is a way

you should add

```
static mapWith = "mongo"
```

in  your domain class for example

```
class Example {
  static mapWith = "mongo"
  ObjectId id
  String someProperty
}
```

And the best solution is make abstract class which contained some property like

```
abstract class BaseDomain implements Serializable {
    static mapWith = "mongo"
    ObjectId id
}
```

Then extend it on your domain classes

```
class Example extends BaseDomain{
  String someProperty
}
```

Comment: I think my question was a little confusing. Thanks for your answer anyway. I knew about the `static mapWith` property to make my domain classes handled by mangoDB. What I am actually looking for is a way to assign plugin domain classes to MongoDB. Ex: I added the `spring security ui plugin` to my app which has a `RegistrationCode` domain class. It is handled by Hibernate by default. What would be the cleanest way to have it handled by MongoDB, knowing this domain class is in the plugin code, not directly in my app code ?